# Force experienced on two particles in a rotating system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, soft-question, rotational-dynamics

I've a system of two particles of the same mass who rotate in a circle about the centre of mass of the two particles. Is the force experienced by the particles $F=MV^{2}/r$ or should I use $Torque=$Moment of Inertia*angular acceleration?

Comment: A hint: is such a system undergoing angular acceleration? Also have a read of the "circular motion" wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are equally correct in this case. $F = mv^2/R $ is just a consequence of the law for rotational motion, which says $ \tau = I\alpha$ (Torque = Moment of Inertia * Angular acceleration). The former formula may be used in case the objects in consideration are point masses. But the latter, more general version of the formula is applicable for *any* rotating body.